# VBA Userform Populate textbox with cell value based on 2 combobox selections

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to populate textbox on userform based on 2 combobox selections? I cannot find any code to get close to this i can populate with 1 combobox but not 2 can anyone help?

Example if combobox1 = Cell E3 (Period 1) & combobox2 = Cell E4 (week) show Cell value E6 in Textbox1

[image]

[image]

If anyone can help I would be very greatful

Comment: What are the values of the ComboBoxes?

Comment: Combobox 1 = Period 1, Period 2.... Period 13, Combobox2 = Week 1, Week 2, week 3 & week 4

Comment: You could use `FoundRange = Range().Find()` to search for the ComboBox1 Value in the sheet. And `FoundRange.Offset(3, 0)` for Week1 and `FoundRange.Offset(3, 1)` for Week2 etc. Give it a try and come back with your code and a specific question to it (or errors you got).

Comment: Sounds like this way you will have to list all the possibilities, i.e. Period1/Week1, Week2, etc... then Period2/Week1, Week2, etc... if that is what you want, then you could use a label instead of a textbox, for example name it DisplayLabel1 and then declare:  if combobox1 = Cell E3 (Period 1) & combobox2 = Cell E4 (week) then DisplayLabel1.Caption = "whatever cell address content is supposed to display".value... then another if and another...

Comment: Is there any pattern of selecting a cell after week/period was selected? Eg if week 1 is selected will it be always cell in row 6 no matter which period was selected? If yes then you could use hidden columns in comboboxes and put rows/columns numbers in there. Eg Period 1 is column 5 and week 1 is row 6 and offset 0. So cell to select is .cells(6,5).offset(0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concentrating the 2 text boxes in to 1 value and searching solved this issue

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim Inp, Outp
    Dim Rng As Range
    Inp = TextBox1.Value
    With Sheets("2018 - 2019").Range("E2:H2")
        Set Rng = .Find(what:=Inp, after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Outp = Rng.Offset(5, 0).Value
            TextBox2.Value = Outp
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```